# Lua process vararg in function process only 1st parameter

Tags: lua, functional-programming, variadic-functions

I'm trying to get a bit tricky logging, but can't get why `...` processing only 1st parameter in a function called

I have this function

```
local logger = function (name, ...)
    -- Expected table processing here, but no.
    print("[" .. name .. "] log called with " .. ...)
end

return setmetatable({}, {__index = function(self, name)
    local log = function(...)
        return logger(name, ...)
    end
    self[name] = log
    return log
end})
```

And how it's called

```
local testf = require "test_log"["TestA"]

testf("TestB", "TestC")
testf("TestC", "TestB")
```

But getting back this result

```
[TestA] log called with TestB
[TestA] log called with TestC
```

The problem I can't get 2nd (and further) parameters from `testf` function and can't get why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace `print("[" .. name .. "] log called with " .. ...)` with `print("[" .. name .. "] log called with", ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses only first parameter

```
local s = ''
for i=1,select('#',...) do s = s .. select(i, ...) end
print("[" .. name .. "] log called with " .. s)
```

Also, you can use `s = table.concat({...})`, but it will produce different results in cases where vararg contains nil values

Comment: `in cases where vararg contains nil values` your code will raise error "attempt to concatenate a nil value"

Comment: I know. An it can be fixed. With table.concat you got just trimmed result

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate `...` because it's not a value. Instead, Lua just takes the first value of the list.

If you want to concatenate more than one value, use `table.concat` first:

```lua
local concatenated = table.concat({...})
```

You could also do something like this instead if you're feeling particularly smart today:

```lua
local logger = function (...)
   print(string.format("[%s] log called with"..string.rep(" %s", select("#")), ...))
end
```